# Commit log and sstables gets corrupted frequently in a write heavy system

Tags: cassandra

I am facing multiple errors due to Commit log and sstables getting corrupted frequently in my write heavy system. Writes are around 50K rows/s.  I have couple of questions around the same.

1. What are the common causes, why commit logs and sstables get corrupted often? How to debug this issue?
2. In my test system where I can bear loss of data, I can delete corrupted commit log file and restart service. How to handle this situation in production environment, with no loss of data?

Exception seen:

1.

> ERROR [main] 2017-01-05 06:42:38,787 JVMStabilityInspector.java (line 78) Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization.
>   org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException: Could not read commit log descriptor in file /a
>   /CommitLog-5-1483596903961.log
>            at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.handleReplayError(CommitLogReplayer.java:623) [main/:na]
>            at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:303) [main/:na]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer.recover(CommitLogReplayer.java:147) [main/:na]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:189) [main/:na]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.recover(CommitLog.java:169) [main/:na]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:303) [main/:na]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:543) [main/:na]
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:652) [main/:na]

2.

> org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException: Mutation checksum failure at 96490970 in CommitLog-5-1483586548946.log

Comment: is your cassandra process being killed often? OOM killer maybe?

Comment: Yes, we do that often because everytime we see corrupted commit log, we delete file and restart service.

Comment: That error is from startup, not while running. Most of time this happens if shut down not cleanly, the next startup it will get stuck on the commitlog it was in middle of flushing. You can set the disk failure policy to continue and it will just replay as much of the commitlog as it can.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. I believe  disk_failure_policy is for reading any sstables from disk, and it doesn't apply for commit_logs right? Are you referring to commit_failure_policy? And I believe commit_failure_policy is only for errors on write and not on readin commit_logs.

Comment: Whenever a segment has a failure it checks on if it should stop or continue. https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/af3fe39dcabd9ef77a00309ce6741268423206df/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogReplayer.java#L391 -> https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/af3fe39dcabd9ef77a00309ce6741268423206df/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLog.java#L466